# iPhone CALayer animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am drawing a line animation, connecting 2 points with a line.  This is my code:

```
-(void) drawObject{     
    rootLayer   = [CALayer layer];
    rootLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:rootLayer];

    lineStartPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(lineStartPath, nil, 160, 50);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(lineStartPath, nil, 160, 50);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(lineStartPath);

    lineEndPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(lineEndPath, nil, 160, 50);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(lineEndPath, nil, 160, 300);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(lineEndPath);

    shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = lineStartPath;
    UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.557 saturation:0.55 brightness:0.96 alpha:1.0];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;

    [rootLayer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

-(void) startAnimation{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.duration = 0.5;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.fromValue = (id)lineStartPath;
    animation.toValue = (id)lineEndPath;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
}
```

The weak point is after the animation is ended, the line disappears. I want that after my line is drawn between those 2 points, id does not disappear. Give me a hint please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
shapeLayer.path = lineEndPath;
```

at the beginning of `startAnimation`.

It's explained in this video: [Session 424 - Core Animation in Practice, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) from the WWDC 2010 (around 38:00).

<s>and replace `[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];` with `[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"path"];`.</s>

Comment: The key when you add an animation can be whatever you want, it is only used to get the animation back using `[myLayer animationForKey:@"myKey"];`